# How Can I Filter Rooms Slot As Already Reservated. I need room ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am coding multivendor hotel reservation system and I need to filter rooms of hotels as reservation full or not. I have two table one is include rooms info and one is reservations info. I have room_quota and I try to do when customer pick dates check-in and check-out mysql code count reservation include dates and subtract room_quota if room_quota = 0 the room_id drop the lists.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34e1d/15 you can check table I just can show certain date how many reservation is make. But I need subtract from room_quota and showing results of > 0 just room_id

SQL fiddle contain whole code but if you want to see here is table :

```
CREATE TABLE `reservation_list` (
  `reservation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reservation_check_in_date` date NOT NULL,
  `reservation_check_out_date` date NOT NULL,
  `reservation_price_total` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reservation_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `reservation_list` (`reservation_id`, `room_id`, `customer_id`, `reservation_check_in_date`, `reservation_check_out_date`, `reservation_price_total`, `reservation_status`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1, '2019-07-21', '2019-07-24', 150, 0),
(2, 26, 2, '2019-07-25', '2019-07-30', 250, 1),
(3, 3, 3, '2019-08-21', '2019-08-30', 950, 2),
(4, 4, 4, '2019-08-21', '2019-08-30', 500, 2),
(5, 1, 1, '2019-07-25', '2019-07-30', 250, 1),
(6, 1, 3, '2019-07-21', '2019-07-24', 150, 0);

CREATE TABLE `room_list_hotel` (
  `room_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `hotel_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `room_type` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `room_price` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `room_quota` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `room_m2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `room_list_hotel` (`room_id`, `hotel_id`, `room_type`, `room_price`, `room_quota`, `room_m2`, `room_status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1,  50, 25, 0, 1),
(2, 2, 2, 65, 35, 0, 1),
(3, 3, 1,  75, 15, 0, 1),
(4, 4, 2,  35, 5, 0, 1);
```

Query is that:

```
SELECT reservation_list.room_id, 
COUNT(reservation_list.reservation_id) AS reservation_total_that_days
FROM  reservation_list WHERE reservation_list.room_id IN 
( SELECT reservation_list.room_id FROM reservation_list
 WHERE (reservation_list.reservation_check_in_date<='2019-07-21' and 
        reservation_list.reservation_check_out_date>='2019-07-21') OR 
 (reservation_list.reservation_check_in_date<'2019-07-24' and 
  reservation_list.reservation_check_out_date>='2019-07-24') OR 
 (reservation_list.reservation_check_in_date>='2019-07-21' and 
  reservation_list.reservation_check_out_date<'2019-07-24')) 
  GROUP BY reservation_list.room_id
```

EDİT:

I need to room_id's that have free slot after the certain date reservation quantity subtract from room all slots. I just need room_id because of I'm using in PHP filter.

Result must be looking like this:

```
+---------+------------+-----------+------------+
| room id | room_quota | total_res | FREE SLOTS |
+---------+------------+-----------+------------+
| 1       |         25 |         2 |         23 |
| 2       |          6 |         6 |          0 |
| 3       |         15 |         0 |         15 |
| 4       |         25 |           |          5 |
+---------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and post the expected result for this sample data.

Comment: I added what exactly I want.

Comment: 'I need to room_id's that have free slot after the certain date reservation quantity subtract from room all slots. I just need room_id because of I'm using in PHP filter.' @Strawberry

Comment: is it not clear? @Strawberry

Comment: "Draw" an ASCII table with data which you want to get as result.

Comment: sorry I am new here, and it is my first question. I am adding sample result

Comment: I added as a image @PaulSpiegel

Comment: I have no idea, how to get the desired result from your data. Sample data and expected result don't seem to fit. Also I don't understand the meaning of the data. Do you really want to put 35 people into one room?

Comment: No it is a kind of listing, every hotel has chance define different type of room and this room type has capacity for same time stay. That means there is a different kind of rooms and every kind of rooms has to be count. For example hotel 1 has two different type of room but in total 50 room. 30 rooms are type 1 and 20 rooms are type 2 etc. Is that Clear right now?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an intermediate result.

```
SELECT h.room_id
     , h.room_quota
     , r.reservation_id 
     , r.reservation_check_in_date checkin
     , r.reservation_check_out_date  checkout
  FROM room_list_hotel h 
  LEFT 
  JOIN reservation_list r 
    ON r.room_id = h.room_id 
   AND r.reservation_check_in_date <= '2019-07-24' 
   AND r.reservation_check_out_date >= '2019-07-21';

+---------+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
| room_id | room_quota | reservation_id | checkin    | checkout   |
+---------+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
|       2 |         35 |              1 | 2019-07-21 | 2019-07-24 |
|       1 |         25 |              6 | 2019-07-21 | 2019-07-24 |
|       3 |         15 |           NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
|       4 |          5 |           NULL | NULL       | NULL       |
+---------+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

I can't see how you get from here to your desired result. !?!

EDIT:

Your current result looks like this:

```
+---------+------------+-----------+------------+
| room id | room_quota | total_res | FREE SLOTS |
+---------+------------+-----------+------------+
| 1       |         25 |         2 |         23 | <-- THIS SAYS 23
```

Comment: it is not third colum 'reservation_id ' it is **total_reserved_certain_days** that means check_in and check_out range the room has reservations the total number. So fourth colum means (room_quota )- (total_reserved_certain_days)= FREE SLOT it is a subtract operation

Comment: I would like to subtract the total number of reservations that the room has from the maximum number of bookings that based on customer search between the dates. My main problem here is that the number of bookings in the room needs to be determined dynamically as the search dates of the customer can change, so I cannot perform the substract operation because one of data is not constant. Simply put, all I want to do is substract data from two different tables. However, while the data in one table is fixed, the data in the other table must be dynawmic, not constant.

Comment: Yes it is correct but I need how much reservation rooms 1 and 2 in the table? I need to see one booking because for example room 1 quota 25 and that day there is a one booking so total free slot = 24. I need to see **25-1=24** as a result. Also thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your result says '23'

Comment: How? I don't understand. My result have to calculate **25(room_quota)-1(booked that desired day customer search)=24(it is a free place bookable)** is that clear?

Comment: See my EDIT above

Comment: ah sorry yes it is right. How can you make this? Which query did you use?

Comment: How did I make what? Your 'result'? I just copied and pasted your 'result' !?!?!